# Let $F$ be any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{R}$ as a proper subfield.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Things I know:

[image: Sequence of subfields]

$\mathbb{R}$ is a proper subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

How can I show $i \in F$?

My attempt at the solution:

Let $F=\{a+bi : a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

I assigned $a=0,b=1$ and voilà, I obtain $i$.

Comment: You need to so some work here. If $\mathbb{R}$ is a proper subset, then there is some element that...

Comment: @copper.hat Didn't mean to spoil your hint.

Comment: @BenWest: You had posted before my comment, but I only figured that out afterwards :-).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022937/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb C$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, of dimension $2$. If $F$ is a subfield strictly containing $\mathbb R$, it must have dimension $2$, so must be the whole of $\mathbb C$.

Another proof:$F$ contains $\mathbb R$ strictly, hence there is some $x+yi \in F$ with $y \neq 0$. Therefore $ yi = x+yi - x \in F$, so $i = \frac{yi}{y} \in F$. Hence, $F$ must be $\mathbb C$ again.

Answer (score 6):

Since $F$ properly contains $\mathbb{R}$, there exists some $a+bi\in F$ with $b\neq 0$. Then $b^{-1}((a+bi)-a)=i\in F$.

In your proposed solution, you're essentially assuming $F=\mathbb{C}$ from the get go, so the solution isn't valid.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to think about this is by considering the tower $\mathbb{R} \subsetneq F \subset \mathbb{C}$ and the [degrees of these extension fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension).  By multiplicativity of degrees, we have $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}] = [\mathbb{C}:F] \cdot [F: \mathbb{R}]$.

We can prove that $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}] = 2$ by noting $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$.  We also have $[F:\mathbb{R}] > 1$ since the reals are a *proper* subfield of $F$.  It follows that $[\mathbb{C}:F] = 1$.

I'll leave it to you to prove that, given fields $L \subseteq K$, if $[K:L] = 1$, then in fact $L = K$.